# How to set SET VS90COMNTOOLS=%VS110COMNTOOLS%

Tags: python, visual-studio-2012, mahotas

From this question:
[error: Unable to find vcvarsall.bat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2817869/error-unable-to-find-vcvarsall-bat)

Where is it that I use:
SET VS90COMNTOOLS=%VS110COMNTOOLS%

I'm trying to install the mahotas module to use for python, thanks!

Comment: Not answering your question, but maybe solving your problem: have you tried using a prebuilt package for mahotas? see http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You enter that command in the windows command prompt, cmd.exe.